# Phantom JS + Angular JS - Parse Error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, bdd, karma-runner

I'm getting `SyntaxError: Parse error` while executing unit tests with Karma on PhantomJS.

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) ERROR
    SyntaxError: Parse error
    at d:/Path/To/File/index.html.js.js.js.js:11
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.512 secs / 0 secs)
```

At this line in mentioned html file, I have a conditional angular statement:

```
{{ condition && "String with an escaped \' apostrophe" || "Another string without any escaped characters."}}
```

When I remove this escaped apostrophe, it works fine. I'm using Angular 1.0.8, Karma 1.4.14 and PhantomJS 1.9.7. I want to know if there is a workaround without updating any packages. And I very much like to keep this apostrophe. Thank you.

**Edit**

On chrome I'm getting this error:

```
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 7) ERROR
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at d:/Path/To/File/index.html.js:11
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (2.576 secs / 0 secs)
```

Comment: Have you tested it on another webkit based browser?

Comment: @coma Yes I did. Let me update the question with what I'm getting on chrome.

Comment: Why does the apostrophe (single quote) need to be escaped here? The single quote is inside a double quote. Does removing the backslash change anything? (I ask the last question b/c I'm not sure if you're removing "\\`" or just "\" when it works). Also, you might do yourself a favor and get over your requirement to not update any packages, Angular JS 1.0.8 is so old ... it might be worth the one time headaches to get on the current version.

Comment: @SunilD. I escaped it because IDE (Webstrom) gave me something like this http://i.imgur.com/dxwrm0U.png when I wasn't escaping it. So I thought it was an actual error. Thank you. And its a deployed application, updating angular would cause me a lot of other issues.

Comment: @Umayr Thanks for explaining :) I use RubyMine (a close cousin of WebStorm), and I know what you mean about the syntax highlighting. WebStorm and RubyMine are excellent IDE's, but lately it's syntax highlighting seems a bit off :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you don't need to escape single quotes in a double quoted string. `"'"` produces a string with an apostrophe. `"\'"` is invalid, because `\'` is an invalid escape sequence. If you want to produce a string with a backslash before an apostrophe you'll need to do `"\\'"`, escaping the backslash.

Comment: Alright. That was actually what I did in first place, but then I got something like this in IDE (Webstrom 8.0.4) http://i.imgur.com/dxwrm0U.png. It was confusing if it was an actual error or some bug in IDE. Thank you for clearing up for me.